# Problem by implementing Sutton's One-Step Actor-Critic pseudocode in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pseudocode, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement the pseudocode shown below in Python3 without PyTorch.

[image: Suttons Pseudocode for Actor-Critic method]

---

I have read some chapters from [Reinforcement Learning:
An Introduction (Draft)](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) in the last few days, so I could say that:

1. `PI = exp(h(s,a,Theta)) / sum[b](exp(h(s,b,Theta))`
2. `h = Transpose(Theta) X(s,a)`
3. `v_hat = Transpose(W) X(s)`

But there is something I didn't read:

> What is `X(s)`?

I haven't found it in the book yet. Can someone explain this to me or give me the page of the book that this is explained in?

Comment: Page 16 -> `x(s) : vector of features visible when in state s`. Does this help you in any way?

Comment: Do you have a more detailed answer? So, what exactly are features in this context?

Comment: @Mat if i recall correctly, features in this context are coordinates in tiles&tilings (provided you are using tiling).